# How many money rocks are there?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I'm getting kind of broke in Animal Crossing: New Leaf, so I've started to look for money rocks. How many money rocks are there in total?

Comment: If you're having trouble making money, I suggest going to the island and catching sharks and beetles from there for 30-40 minutes at night after 7:00 PM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Occasionally you will find a rock filled with ore that works the same as a money rock - each time hit, a piece of ore comes out. That happens instead of a money rock.
Had it happen to me today. There was still a rock that broke and had 1 piece of ore inside in the town.
Also you can get up to I think 16,000 bells from one money rock if you're quick enough.
I'd recommend island fishing and beetle hunting after 4PM though, if you're broke. Sharks galore!

Comment: So, one money rock, one ore rock, and a plain ore rock? Or one money rock or ore rock and one plain ore rock?

Comment: That's one "fake" rock per day, which contains an ore, and one money rock per day, which will not break and has a chance of dropping ores instead of bells.

Comment: Just to add to this. Once you get the silver shovel the money rock has a chance of becoming an ore rock and will spit out multiple ore instead of bells. Which can sell for quite a bit.

Answer (score 9):

There is one money rock per day, and one ore rock per day.

Answer (score 2):

One of your existing rocks turn into a money rock each day aswell as a new rock which will break when you hit it with a shovel and drops an ore. When you use a silver shovel on a money rock, there is a chance the money turns into ores.